# Android studio setting notification reminder for app weekly - day before app

Tags: android

I have weekly notifications set up using the calendar and datepicker. However, this notification I am trying to set up uses a date from a database which is converted into milliseconds. The variable which contains the milliseconds is used as the time to fire the reminder. However it will not work. The code does not throw any errors, th enotification simply doesnt fire. My code is below.

MainActivity - used to trigger the notification

```
// Variable pulled from mysql with the app date
private String firstAppointment;

// Date of first app converted from String to Date format
private Date dateOfFirstAppointment;

// Date converted into milliseconds for the notification.
 private long appointmentInMilliseconds;

 /**
 * Method used to format the date from the MYSQL server
 */
private void getFirstAppointment() {

    String myDate = firstAppointment;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    try {
        dateOfFirstAppointment = sdf.parse(myDate);
        appointmentInMilliseconds = dateOfFirstAppointment.getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Method which sets a weekly notification
 */
private void appointmentReminder() {

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver2.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 5, intent, 0);

    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, appointmentInMilliseconds, pendingIntent);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, appointmentInMilliseconds, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, pendingIntent);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Appointment Reminder Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Notification Class :

```
public class NotificationHelperChannel2 extends ContextWrapper {

public static final String channe2ID = "channe2ID";
public static final String channe2Name = "Channe2 Name";

private NotificationManager mManager;

public NotificationHelperChannel2(Context base) {
    super(base);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        createChannel();
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void createChannel() {
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channe2ID, channe2Name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

    getManager2().createNotificationChannel(channel);
}

public NotificationManager getManager2() {
    if (mManager == null) {
        mManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }

    return mManager;
}

public NotificationCompat.Builder getChannelNotification2() {
    return new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), channe2ID)
            .setContentTitle("Appointment Reminder")
            .setContentText("You have an appointment tomorrow")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_icon)
            .setLargeIcon(icon)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
            .setVibrate(new long []{1000, 1000})
            .setLights(Color.RED, 3000, 3000)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

}

Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
        R.drawable.brain_meditate_icon);
}
```

Alert Receiver Class:

```
public class AlertReceiver2 extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    NotificationHelperChannel2 notificationHelper2 = new NotificationHelperChannel2(context);
    NotificationCompat.Builder nb2 = notificationHelper2.getChannelNotification2();
    notificationHelper2.getManager2().notify(2, nb2.build());
}
```

}

Comment: What is the version of your phone?  Like oreo,  naught,  etc

Answer (score 0):

The notifications have different handling in different android operating system.
Possible that the alarm wont work because you are probably using a Pie, Oreo or at least Nougat Android in which requires a special handling

Here is my code in handling notification in Oreo, Pie and Nougat.

Might help you out.

```
      NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            int notificationId = 1;
            String channelId = "channel-01";
            String channelName = "Channel Name";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                        channelId, channelName, importance);
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
            }

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_check)
                    .setContentTitle("Branch Checklist")
                    .setContentText(resultValue)
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 250})
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                    .bigText(resultValue));

//        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
//        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
//        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
//                0,
//                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
//        );
//        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

            notificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());
```